# Pygrib Open encoding error

Tags: python, encoding, grib, pygrib

I'm trying to get `pygrib` to work in Python 3.5.
I have imported it in my program, I have assigned the grib file to a variable (grib).

But when I try to run the command:

`grbs=pygrib.open(grib)`

I get the following error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>       print(sys.getdefault_encoding())
>
> AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'getdefault_encoding'

No google search led me to any understanding of the problem.

What does this error actually mean?

Comment: I don't think the under-scroll should be there. See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding)

Comment: Thanks Tim,
You mean there would be an error in their program?
If this is the case, where do I access the program to remove the extra underscore?

Comment: Error seems to be in:

  File "pygrib.pyx", line 391, in pygrib.open.__cinit__ (pygrib.c:2902)

  File "pygrib.pyx", line 2070, in pygrib._strencode (pygrib.c:32191)

NameError: name 'default_encoding' is not defined

But where are these files?

Comment: Can you show us the actual program? I just installed & used it without issues.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's ointeresting. Yes I'll post it in the morning. May be versions or dependencies...

Comment: I'm curious about how you managed to install it so quickly though. I've been on it for days trying to figure it out...

Comment: See code linked. That's the best way I found:

https://imgur.com/a/2F2OW

Comment: I normally don't use [conda/miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) however it is easy to get something up and running quickly: `conda create --channel conda-forge --name test pygrib`. Glad it's working for you now.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks